# Should we separate guitar tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should separate [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) tag. So, the question will be more specific.

So, no one can use the [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) tag, and they can change it into [acoustic-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-guitar) or [electric-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-guitar).

I've search in the meta, I didn't found this kind of request yet, and I don't know if this request ever discussed.

Comment: What if it is a general question about the guitar like "Why the standard tuning of a guitar EADGBE?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not want this to be separated. We do have [acoustic-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-guitar) and [electric-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-guitar) for those occasions where a question specifically refers to one or the other, but many guitar questions are appropriate for both, for example, questions about how to play certain chords, scale patterns, tuning, etc.

The fact that we have 3 tags here isn't a problem - this isn't tag proliferation like some sites have.

Comment: I have seen situations where someone will tag guitar and acoustic-guitar or guitar and electric-guitar. We should eventually fix those tagging when applicable.

Comment: @Dom Is that an issue? If people are following tags, they might only be getting `guitar` instead of all three.

Comment: @NReilingh For some questions it might not be, but for others might be. I know that some questions are tagged with two of the three tags above and I think it should be looked in to eventually if only for consistency's sake.

Comment: tags are just to help people find the questions, so having two of the three is absolutely fine.